# Check from Code1.java if string used in code2.java is normalized after declaration in sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube, unicode-normalization

I am writing a code in Java for SonarQube where code1.java will scan code2.java to check if the string used in code2.java is normalized. If normalize, pass a message of yes else no. I am pretty new to Java.

Code1.java

```java
public class NormalizeStringsBeforeValidatingRule extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor {
        
    private static final String JAVA_LANG_STRING = "java.lang.string";
    static Boolean flag;
    @Override
    public List<Tree.Kind>  nodesToVisit() {
        return Arrays.asList(Tree.Kind.VARIABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
        tree.accept(new MembersReferenceVisitor());
    }
    
    private static Tree immediateParentOfKind(Kind k, Tree t) {
        if (t.parent() != null && !t.parent().is(k)) {
            return immediateParentOfKind(k, t.parent());
        }
        return t.parent();
    }
    
    private static class MembersReferenceVisitor extends BaseTreeVisitor {

        @Override
        public void visitVariable(VariableTree tree) {
    
        //***Logic to get if code2.java is having string and if it's normalized***    
         }
    }
```

Code2.java

```java
public class userInput {
    // String s may be user controllable
    // \uFE64 is normalized to < and \uFE65 is normalized to > using the NFKC normalization form
    String s = "\uFE64" + "script" + "\uFE65"; // ----
    // ***
    // Normalize
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Form.NFKC); 
    // ***
    // Validate
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[<>]"); // Check for angle brackets
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        // Found black listed tag
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked this before, and should update your previous question with more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955619/to-check-if-string-is-normalize-in-java

Comment: Hi..I have updated it with the exact scenario.

Comment: Set out the problem as minimal reproducable test case - for example as `main(String[]args)' and details of your input data which highlight the issue.